# How can repository pattern fit with OOP encapsulation principle?

Tags: java, oop, domain-driven-design, repository-pattern, encapsulation

Let's say we have a class `Event`:

```
class Event {

  private final Long id;
  private final Date date;

  //constructor and other stuff

  public boolean hasExpired() {
    return date > today();
  }

}
```

As you see, its public interface is just a method `hasExpired`, and this uses `Event` internal state (`date`) to perform the logic.

Now, we want to save this `Event` to database, using a repository:

```
class EventRepository {

  public void saveEvent(Event event) {
    //insert into events...
  }

}
```

How is this done without violating OOP encapsulation principle?

Repository needs to know `Event`'s `date` in order to persist it. Adding a `getDate` method would violate encapsulation principle.

Comment: Why do you think that encapsulation is violated?

Comment: Because the public interface for `Event` class is just `hasExpired` method. I don't want other state to be exposed.

Comment: Well ... libraries like Hibernate (e.g.) usually do this by using a refelctive acces. Nothing is _exposed_.

Comment: Let's say I don't want any libraries dependencies nor using relfection, but a real good design.

Comment: Then do not use your domain model as the persistence model! Use separate classes.

Comment: Of course, but the problem is still here. I could have a "EventRow" (representing a database register), but how it reads the internal state from `Event`?

Comment: ... by having a `createEventRow()` method in your `Event` class. Or you could have some method like `save(Database db)` in your model classes. There are many ways.

Comment: The `Event#saveTo(Database)` would be the OOP approach. You will be telling the object to perform a behavior. No internals of `Event` will be exposed.

Comment: Have you seen that approach in any project?

Comment: @Héctor Yes, serialization is an example. All classes have a `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream)` method, where the entity being stored is in charge of specifying which of it's state will be stored. In your case, `Database` would act as the output stream. It doesn't have to be an actual database either, you could pass a buffer to `saveTo`, allow the event to populate the buffer, then have a system which parses the buffer to store in a DB. You get the benefit of not having to expose what state the event is storing (easy modification). `readFrom(Database)` could restore/read back the data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How is this done without violating OOP encapsulation principle?

You change your interpretation of the encapsulation principle.

*Somewhere* in our system we need to have two functions: one that takes the in memory representation of the entity and converts it to the stored representation of the entity, and other function that reconstitutes the entity from the stored representation.

For instance, you might have a method on the entity that returns a JSON representation of a memento, and then a constructor on the entity that accepts a JSON representation and uses it to initialize the object.

In effect, this is an application of the Memento pattern from the GoF book.  Or you can think of it as a message that is being sent from/to the entity.

This message isn't necessarily a copy of the data structure of the entity; it might be expressing that information in a different way, it might not be sharing all of the information, and so on.  But if you want to get the information back into an entity later, you have to be able to copy it out now.

Another way of thinking about this that may help: we don't store "entities", or send entities over the network -- we send *values* over the network; the information is packed into some well understood schema so that we can unpack the information later.

The reasons that we can argue that this isn't a violation of "encapsulation" is two fold: first, the memento is a copy -- a *deep* copy -- of the information.  We can't change the existing entity's state by changing the memento.  Second, there's no promise or implied guarantee that the memento has the same data structure as the entity itself.

What *does* fall over is the assumption that you can implement the entity with no code that is influenced by your persistence strategy, because you need to be able to get the information out of the data store somehow.

Comment: This would not be a memento. In the Memento pattern, the properties are still hidden within the originator. Even if the caretaker requests a memento, the caretaker has no information on what the memento is storing. Your example would not be similar to the Memento pattern, as underlying details of the originator (properties of the event) is exposed to the caretaker, which violates encapuslation.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to define `Event` to be storable. The whole idea behind OOP is to tell objects to perform behaviors. You want to store the state of `Event`, but can't expose the state without sacrificing the flexibility encapsulation provides.

This is very similar to serializing objects, where their internal state must be written to a stream. This is handled by having each serializable class define a `writeObject(ObjectOutputStream)` to specify how it should be serialized.

You could provide a `saveTo(DataStorage storage)`, letting clients know that the data from the event can be stored externally. As with all storage of internal data, this leaks implementation, as someone can view the storage to view what implementation details `Event` decided to store. To read the data back, `Event` would provide a `restoreFrom(DataStorage storage)`.

Not only do you keep implementation hidden from clients (not including the leakage from writing internal state, that's inevitable when writing internal state), but you can provide different forms of `DataStorage`: maybe you want to save right to the database, or maybe you want a `DataStorageBuffer` to obtain the data for later use/parsing/storage.

```
class Event {
    private final Long id;
    private final Date date;

    public Event(Long id, Date date) {
        this.id = id;
        this.date = date;
    }

    public void saveTo(DataStorage storage) {
        // Add state to storage
    }

    public static Event readFrom(DataStorage storage) {
        Long id = ...; // read from storage
        Date date = ...;

        return new Event(id, date);
    }
}
```

Rather than request the information to be stored [via a getter](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/358611/is-encapsulation-still-one-of-the-elephants-oop-stands-on/358622), we are telling the object to store itself, staying aligned with OOP philosophy.